# Creating a set matrix size

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have results which are 6 columns long however have been printed as 2 then 3 beneath then 1 beneath that! There are hundreds of lines and matlab will not except the structure of the matrix as it is now. Is there any way to tell matlab i want the first 5 results in their own columns then continuing down the rows after that?

My results appear as follows:

```
0.5                                  0          

0.59095535915335684063       -0.59095535915335395405    -5.89791913085569763

33e-08
```

... repeated alot

thansk so much, em xx

Comment: Dude, you'll have to make a better effort to explain to us what you want!

Answer (score 0):

I would just do a `format shortE` before you process the output, this will give you everything in scientific notation with 4 digits after the decimal. That 'should' allow you to fit your columns all in one line, so you don't have to deal with the botched output.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should not want the output to be in a too specific format, but suppose you have this matrix:

```
M =[0.5                                  0          0.59095535915335684063     -0.59095535915335395405    -5.89791913085569763 33e-08];
```

To make it an actual matrix I will repeat it a bit:

```
M = repmat(M,10,1);
```

Now you can ensure that all six columns will fit on a normal screen by using the format.

```
format short
```

Try `help format` to find more options. Now simply showing the matrix will put all columns next to eachother. If you want one column below, the trick is to reduce your windows width untill it can only hold five columns. Matlab will now print the last column below the first.

```
M % Simply show the matrix
% Now reduce your window size

M % Simply show it again
```

---

This should help you display the numbers in matlab, if you want to process them further you can consider to write them to a file instead. Try `help xlswrite` for a simple solution.